# How to JOIN category table for parents in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a table for posts as (id, category_id, ...), then `JOIN` it with the category table as (category_id, category_name, parent, ...) ON `category_id`. Parent is the category_id of another category. For example:

```
category_id    category_name      parent
1              Computer Science   NULL
2              Web Technology     1
3              Mathematics        NULL
4              PHP                2
```

How can I `JOIN` posts and category tables to read parent categories of a post too. For example,

```
id     category_id    post_title
44     4              something
```

With simple `JOIN` ON category_id, I can get only PHP as category; how can I get the parents too as `Computer Science > Web Technology > PHP` ?

**NOTE:** I use mysql with MyISAM engine.

Comment: Several examples already exist on Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689635 to name one. The long and short of it is mySQL doesn't support hierarchical queries, so you'll have to write something. in Oracle they use connect by prior. SQL server DB2 use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804 (with)

Comment: Well, it seems to be a challenging issue. I thought there is a simple method that I've missed.

Comment: sadly no; not in mysql; if you have a max number of levels then adding left (self) joins is the easiest; but that first link links off to other answers shwoing some common solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do an additional join for the extra element, but have IT as a LEFT join as not all categories have a parent category and you don't want to exclude those.

```
select
      P.ID,
      P.Post_Title,
      P.Category_ID,
      C.Category_Name as FirstCat,
      C.Parent,
      COALESCE( C2.Category_Name, ' ' ) as ParentCategory
   from
      Posts P
         JOIN Categories C
            on P.Category_ID = C.Category_ID
            LEFT JOIN Categories C2
               on C.Parent = C2.Category_ID
   where
      AnyFiltering
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to limit the depth, you can use `UNION` to stack up `JOIN`s to get what you want. Here's a 3-level deep implementation:

```
select * from posts
where category_id = ?
union
select * from posts p
join category c on c.category_id = p.category_id
where c.parent = ?
union
select * from posts p
join category c1 on c1.category_id = p.category_id
join category c2 on c2.category_id = c1.parent
where c2.parent = ?
```

You would pass the same variable in (for the category you're interested in) for all 3 placeholders.