# What is the equivalent Doctrine SQL query for getting a recursive query on item's categories

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542201/how-to-join-category-table-for-parents-in-sql-query), **DRapp** provided an SQL query for solving the problem proposed by **Ali**. In practice, Ali asked how to write a query capable of returning all the rows from the table *Category* related to a row in the *Post* table, in order to do what we can see in all the catalog-based websites (eBay, Amazon, etc.).

This stated, **how the SQL query** proposed in the *DRapp's solution* **can be written with Doctrine2**?

Please, **avoid** using **QueryBuilder**.

PS: I use MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is not possible to write such a query like the one mentioned in the question by using DQL or the QueryBuilder directly. However, one possibility is to use [Doctrine2 Native Query](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-native-queries.html), which let the use to execute a raw SQL.

For sake of completeness, here follows the query by [DRapp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74195/drapp).

```
select
      P.ID,
      P.Post_Title,
      P.Category_ID,
      C.Category_Name as FirstCat,
      C.Parent,
      COALESCE( C2.Category_Name, ' ' ) as ParentCategory
   from
      Posts P
         JOIN Categories C
            on P.Category_ID = C.Category_ID
            LEFT JOIN Categories C2
               on C.Parent = C2.Category_ID
   where
      AnyFiltering
```