# Print Posts from all categories and their categories names

Tags: php

I try to achieve the following:

- Some great post title *(posted in Sport)*
- Another title of a post *here (posted in Space)*
- Cool title of some post *(posted in Technologies)*
- And so on...

I display all posts from all categories and put the category name next to each post.
I do not understand where and why fail. All posts are multiplied by the number of categories.
Here is what I have till now:

```
posts table:

post_id
post_title
post_content
category_id



categories table:

category_id
category_name
category_description
```

And my queries and PHP code:

```
// I select all categories with their id and name
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");
$stmt->execute();
$row_categories = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// I select all posts too
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
$stmt->execute();
$row_posts_all = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And then:

```
foreach ($row_posts_all as $array_index_number => $name_of_index) {

    foreach ($row_categories as $array_index_number_categories => $name_of_index_category) {

        print $name_of_index['post_title'] . " posted in: " . $name_of_index_category['category_name'] . "<br><br>";
    }
}
```

I think this two foreaches part do things wrong. I can do one foreach to display all the posts but I do not know how to get their category names and put them next.

Comment: Do you have the reference of category in your post table ? What is that column name ?

Comment: Yes! I am sorry! I forgot one field. I updated my question. I have "category_id" in the `posts` table

Answer (score 1):

That's the reason we have **JOINS**,

```
SELECT * from posts p
LEFT JOIN categories c on c.id = p.category_id
```

And then you can simply need a single loop,

```
foreach ($row_posts_all as $array_index_number => $name_of_index) {
    echo $name_of_index['post_title'] . " posted in: " . $name_of_index['category_name'] . "<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will read about it and practice it now as I do not understand what "p" and "c" are.

Comment: They are nothing but an alias for the tables.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and practice it now. Can you suggest me some reference or idea how can I upgrade the example when posts may have categories and subcategories either. When I search in google about categories, posts etc.. all results are WordPress related. :-/

Comment: In that case refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542201/how-to-join-category-table-for-parents-in-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select P.*, C.* from posts P
inner join categories C on C.category_id = P.category_id
```

You don't need 2 sql requests. So you don't need 2 loops

Comment: Can I achieve the idea without joins because I have not practiced them yet. Do I have to practice joins now to accomplish what I try?